# Open Source .net/C# projects and Frameworks?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I know that with .net you have Asp.net, and I know that .net it's self is a framework. How ever, I am coming from the land of Java and PHP where frameworks are aplenty.

I understand that C# and .net are usually used in business development ans that a lot of the code is not open due to the nature of MS and the platforms used to develop with such technologies.

I have scoured "C#" on github and ".net" on the same site, how ever the code bases I find, seem to be developed for a while and then fade away, and it also seems, chime in if I am wrong, that there are no frameworks for .net, aside from .net it's self. With that said I have seen Spring .net

The reason I ask is because I have recently began reading the Framework Design Guidelines book  which is mostly discussing .net and .net frameworks, how ever when looking for examples on .net frameworks used in production code, I am either blind or there are none.

Are there any? If I was to develop an application is there any frameworks I could draw on aside from .net it's self.

The application could be desktop, database driven, web.....I am just looking to see what .net frameworks exist and how they are used to get a better understanding of this "closed source" world.

Comment: Nido framework is a must check (gain coding speed with Nirosh) https://nidoframework.codeplex.com/documentation.. https://nidoframework.codeplex.com/ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698486/Introduction-to-Nido-FREE-Framework-NET-Csharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find a whole bunch of .NET frameworks that are open-source head on over to [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com), there are a ton of great, active frameworks over there.

A few other things are also open-source from the Microsoft side of things, items like reactive extensions and the such.

GitHub is great but its usage for .NET items is somewhat new-ish and hard to gauge compared to CodePlex.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of open source projects in c# from Microsoft and community.

First of all Asp.net is open source and they accept community contributions. http://aspnet.codeplex.com/

I don't know if you looked https://github.com/languages/C%23 there are also many projects like Mono , [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) and [NancyFx](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy) [Signalr](https://github.com/signalr/signalr) [RavenDb](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb) , [NServiceBus](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus)

And if you check out Nuget's package list you will also see lots of frameworks most of them are open source http://nuget.org/packages

Comment: I don't really count mono as it's not microsft specific, The reason I ask for microsoft specific is because my new job will be with a company using microsoft specific tools and I wanted to see if MS supports Open Source (OS) with any thing or if its like the world paints it.

Comment: I didnt put a link on Mono :))